# persian calendar in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, calendar, persian

i want to use persian calendar in windows phone 8 but i konw `PersianCalendar` is not available in silverlight. i see several persian calendar applications in windows phone store but i don't know whether these application use a persian calendar library or they are implement it by (him/her)self. is it any persian calendar library available for silverlight that i can use it in my application? i see serveral persian date-picker control for silverlight but can not find any jalali calendar for windows phone

Comment: Silverlight `5` supports Persian calendar officially and Silverlight 5 is the platform that you use to develop Windows Phone 8.

Comment: i didn't find PersianCalendar Class in System.Globalization @VahidN